# PHP - HTML Script being placed within 'body' tags

Tags: php, html

I have been developing a page on my webserver (using nano on the actual server) and I have been experimenting with the `INCLUDE` statement as an attempt to hide database details from the end user. However, my html is being placed within `BODY` tags according to Firefox's Inspector.

Here is the result in firefox and below that is the code for my page.

[image]

```
<?php
include "/database.php";
?>
<DOCTYPE! html>
<html>
<head>
<title><?php echo $minfo['name']; ?></title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to my page</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

If its needed I can also include the "DATABASE.PHP" script.

Comment: The syntax is <!DOCTYPE html> and the meta tag before the title

Comment: The end user won't see your PHP code, just what the PHP code outputs.  You don't need to worry about "hiding database details" for web users unless you are explicitly echo-ing them.

Comment: Is that /database.php call outputting anything?  if so, it could be throwing things off.

Comment: Thanks for the bit about DOCTYPE.. I've been dev-ing all day and my tired eyes must have missed that.. Also how difficult would it be for someone to view the PHP script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
include "/database.php";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title><?php echo $minfo['name']; ?></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome to my page</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Assumes that `$minfo['name']` is defined in your `database.php`.

Comment: The only difference between my code and yours (from what I can see) is the tab spacing (correct me if i'm wrong).

That didn't work either.

Comment: @JWassall Check the doctype declaration.